# Showing data in table from 3 different JSON arrays in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a JSON data like

```
{
   tableList:["a","b"], 
   dbList:["c","d"], 
   score:[2 , 5] 
}
```

I want to print this using AngularJS in Table like

```
DB  Table  Score
c    a      2
d    b      5
```

Can we use mltiple ng-repeat with ng-repeat-start in this case? If yes How?

My controller is as follows

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/service').success(function (thisdata) {
        //Convert data to array.
        var myData =  $.parseJSON(JSON.parse(thisdata.tableList));
        $scope.myData  =  myData;
    });

});
```

Is this correct or I need to modify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for start...

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in json">{{key}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in json">
      <td ng-repeat="innerValue in value">{{innerValue}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```